# List connected clients to an iscsi target

Tags: rhel, storage, iscsi, multipath-storage

Is there any way to list the connected clients to an ISCSI target from another client.

While sitting on the target itself , it may be easier to see which clients have mounted a particular target , but sitting on some other client , i may want to see if some ISCSI target is mounted somewhere else before i mount it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way to find this *that I know of*, i.e. there is nothing in the protocol like "show me all the iscsi initiators you are connected to".